# What is the best way to have and use a configurable list of allowable file extensions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-extension

I have the following:

```
string _file; //can have any file path on the file server

if (_file.EndsWith("xls") || _file.EndsWith("pdf") || _file.EndsWith("doc")) 
    return _file;
```

The extensions are hard coded and I need to put them in `web.config` and make it more configurable in a way that it can have 1 allow extension (say `.doc`) or 50 allowed extensions (`.doc`, `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.ppt`, ...).

What do you suggest?

Comment: You are able to use a data structure (array/list) to store the data? If so, that's just an incremental OR operation.

Comment: You could also use a RegEx and then build the expression dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store it in the web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AllowedExtensions" value=".xls,.pdf,.doc" />
</appSettings>
```

Then use [`Path.GetExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to safely get the file extension from the path.

```
var allowedExtensions = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedExtensions"]
                                            .Split(',');

if (allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(_file)))
    return _file;
else
    return ???  // What are you going to return if the extension is invalid?
```

Comment: +1 for using the `Path` library to actually get the file's extension.

Answer (score 2):

First put your allowed extensions in the `app.config` file. Then you can load them into a `List<string>` named `extensions` and use code like this:

```
if (extensions.Any(p => _file.EndsWith(p)))
    return _file;
```

or, if `_file` can be null

```
if (extensions.Any(p => _file!= null && _file.EndsWith(p)))
    return _file;
```

Comment: Answer typed in my smart phones só i'll better format it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

web.config:

```
 <add key="allowed-extensions" value="pdf,jpg,doc" />
```

function to get value from web.config:

```
public static string Get(string Key)
{
    Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
    if (settings[Key] != null)
        return settings[Key].Value;
    else
        return "";
}
```

now the your function would be:

```
bool checkExt(string givenExtension){
    string[] extensions = Get("alowed-extensions");
    for(int i=0;i<extensions.length;i++)
         if(extensions[i]==givenExtension) return true;
         return false;
}
```